# How to suppress a dialog box displayed by code that I can't change?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, com, messagebox

I have a Inproc COM Server from a 3rd party. One of the functions I call will display a error message dialog box if it traps a specific type of error. The issue is I am trying to process data in bulk, and the data source I am using is causing that error dialog to pop up a lot. This would not be a issue if it spawned 1000 dialog boxes, but instead it blocks and the function does not return until you press OK.

[image]

How can I suppress the dialog from showing up, or programmatically press OK?

Here is a copy of the call stack as it is waiting for me to press OK

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) Line 2198 + 0x1e bytes   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 3422 + 0x1b bytes C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 3306 + 0xc bytes   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) Line 1495 + 0x31 bytes    C#
    UniversalDataImporter.exe!UniversalDataImporter.Program.Main() Line 18 + 0x1d bytes C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Line 2023 + 0x18 bytes  C#
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x27 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) Line 68 + 0x27 bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581 + 0xd bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 530 + 0xd bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 519 + 0xe bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() Line 105 + 0x20 bytes  C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

I doubt it will help (there are no options to disable the message box, events to subscribe to, or other overloads to the function) but here is the calling code.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= recordCount; i++)
{
    //If the dialog shows up the following line blocks till you press OK.
    var values = _comServer.GetValues(fileHandle, i); 

    sqlDataConsumer.LoadRow(values);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A message box pumps a message loop.  That's something you can take advantage of, it allows you to inject code with Control.BeginInvoke() that runs as soon as the message box appears.  You can then use that code to find the dialog window and close it.  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class DialogCloser : IDisposable {
    public DialogCloser() {
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        Application.OpenForms[0].BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            // Enumerate windows to find dialogs
            if (cancelled) return;
            EnumThreadWndProc callback = new EnumThreadWndProc(checkWindow);
            EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero);
            GC.KeepAlive(callback);
        }));
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        cancelled = true;
    }

    private static bool checkWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp) {
        // Checks if <hWnd> is a Windows dialog
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(260);
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        if (sb.ToString() == "#32770") {
            // Close it by sending WM_CLOSE to the window
            SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0010, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool cancelled;

    // P/Invoke declarations
    private delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int tid, EnumThreadWndProc callback, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    using (new DialogCloser()) {
        // Replace this with the call to the COM server method:
        MessageBox.Show("you never see this");
    }
}
```

Comment: The COM server is not called on the UI Thread, it is a long running process so I start it in a background Task, will that be a problem with this solution?

Comment: Yes that will be a problem.  Control.BeginInvoke() won't work since the worker doesn't pump a message loop.  And GetCurrentThreadId() returns the wrong thread ID.  In all likelihood, the message box is created on a separate thread that COM created to give the server a home, most COM components require an STA thread.  You'll need something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034

Comment: Thank you, I had to tweek it a little and I have some issues (like now it is flooding the message pump with canceled events) however those issues I know how to fix on my own, I just had to get over the hurdle of getting the window closed in the first place. I will award the bounty in 24 hrs when it lets me.

Comment: If you would like to see my implementation, I posted most of it in a followup question I [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570167/getting-the-text-from-a-dialog-box-spawned-by-a-3rd-party-dll)

Comment: and  using (new DialogCloser()) {
       MessageBox.Show("you never see this");
        MessageBox.Show("you never see this");
    }  will show second box

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would certainly be better if the COM server itself could be turned into mode when it does not let caller down with undesired UI action. Provided that you cannot alter third party component behavior, what you still can do is hooking message processing and forced closing of the message box.

Before doing the call on the third party server, you can install a message hook with `SetWindowsHookEx` and `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and your callback will be able to monitor the messages. In particular you will be able to post messages, hook dialog's WindowProc etc. Including certainly programmatic closing of the message box.

Comment: I have never worked much with message hooks, I agree that this is the solution but I don't know how to implement it, can you provide some example code on how I would set this up? (it does not need to conform to my example, I can figure that out for my self, I just need to get on the right track)

Comment: I have C++ code that does the thing by altering standard message box - adding "do not show" checkbox, and implements timeout to auto-close - I will put it online shortly. Something similar is explained there: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10037/How-to-change-the-MessageBox-window-Add-controls-a