# Closing an application after displaying a message

Tags: c#, exit, messagebox

I have the following code...

```
MessageBox.Show("Your session has been remotely terminated.");
Application.ExitThread;
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to close the MessageBox automatically after a short period of time has elapsed if the user doesn't hit the 'Ok' button.

Comment: Have you tried 'MessageBox.Show("blah", timeout)' yet?

Comment: You can use this code, minus the BeginInvoke hack.  Call it from a timer's Tick event.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12555069/17034

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Microsoft technology called UI Automation