# Programmatically close a FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have timeout functionality built into my application and I am trying to close a FolderBrowserDialog box if that timeout event occurs. Currently I open the dialog like this...

```
fldBrowse.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Since the call come from the main form and works it's way through all owned forms I would've expected this case to be handled, but it's not.

I have also tried subscribing to the event and disposing the dialog but this doesn't seem to work either.

Has anyone achieved this in code?

Comment: You can use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12555069/17034), but call it from a timer's Tick event handler instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
AppActivate("Browse For Folder")
SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}")
```

This should replicate alt+f4 and close the FolderBrowserDialog