# Suppress Popup Windows in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to run an external .exe inside VB.Net. I am using these two objects
to run the external process:

```
Dim pInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim p As Process = Process.Start(pInfo)
```

The .exe contains popups (MsgBox functions).  My questions are:

1. Is it possible to suppress these popups?
2. How can I capture the return value from .exe? The .exe returns 0 or 1.

Comment: Suppressing popups isn't easy, but try looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532812/how-to-suppress-a-dialog-box-displayed-by-code-that-i-cant-change). As far as capturing the return value, it should just be `p.ExitCode`. You might need to call `p.WaitForExit()` first.

Comment: Q1: `yes` with a little work. Q2 : `yes its possible`

Comment: OK.  I will add p.WaitForExit() then follow by p.ExitCode and see if I can capture the return value.  But I need help with Q1.  Would you mind sharing some tips on this if you know how?  Thanks

Comment: @sydney `Would you mind sharing some tips on this` that would require more than likely outside resources, such as tutorials etc... which is off topic here on SO. If you can show us your attempt and where you are stuck we would be glad to help you.

Comment: See here: [How to get the text of a MessageBox when it has an icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55014473/7444103). Two different methods (P/Invoking and UI Automation) to perform the same task. C# code.

Comment: OK.  I'm going to study the links you guys have posted and see if I could follow and get my code to work.  Thanks much.